# Problem in Running Java Application in Non JDK/ Non JRE installed system

Tags: java, installation, desktop

I am working in a java application. It is desktop application for Windows Operating System. I am creating a installer for my application. My application works fine for the system where jdk is insalled. I also want to run my application where jdk/jre is not present.

For this i am providing jre1.7 along with the installer. I am using advanced installer for creating exe form my application's jar file and providing JRE 1.7 along with all the lib files which requires in my application.

When i install application in non jdk/jre system. It gets installed properly but when i try to run the application, it shows "Missing JRE","Java Runtime Environment Not Found."

when i install application it gets successfully installed along with JRE 1.7 lib files.

I want my application to recognize JRE 1.7 automatically, which i am providing along with the installer.

Please guide me that what can be to recognize JRE for my application that i am providing along with the installer.

I thanks to your all valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should [work out of the box](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/bundle-jre.html). Maybe check if you didn't mistakenly bundle an x64 JRE with your app?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to enclose a Java 6 runtime instead.  Java 7 has not been released yet.

It sounds like you are just unpacking the files.  For this to work correctly you must either explicitly invoke the java.exe file in the destination library, or the Java installer must be run to register properly with Windows.

Get the MSI version (for Windows) and tell your installation program to install it.